# Meaning of the columns of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

May I ask you to explain to me the meaning of columns of the matrix in linear algebra please? How can I use it?

Also, in my notes (attached below) it says: "Columns of matrix tell us how the corresponding linear function acts on the basic vectors {e1,...,en} and, quite significantly, these completely determine the matrix."

But columns of the matrix does not represent any linear function. It represents the coefficients of the n-th variable. Isn't it?

[Screenshot of the lecture notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSM35.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_n$ denote the columns of $A$.  Then if $\vec x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$, we have
$$
A\vec x = x_1 \vec v_1 + x_2 \vec v_2 + \cdots + x_n \vec v_n
$$
In other words: a vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$ acts on the matrix $A$ by producing a linear combination of its columns.

---

What you have in mind is the *row* picture.  If $\vec r_1, \dots \vec r_m$ denote the rows of $A$, then we have
$$
A \vec x = \pmatrix{\vec r_1 \cdot \vec x\\ \vdots \\ \vec r_m \cdot \vec x}
$$
Where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product.

It may be hard to see, but we have simply said the same thing in two different ways.

Comment: Thank you. I understand linear combination of columns. That makes sense.  But if we take v1 as a single column of the matrix A. How can v1 tell me how the corresponding linear function acts on the basis vector? Indeed, if I had a row r1 that acts on the vector, that makes sense (you presented that in the second example). But in this case it talks about the columns.

Comment: The basis vector for us is just $x = (1,0,\dots,0)$.  Plugging into the formula, it's clear that $A(1,0,\dots,0) = \vec v_1$